# Laravel 5.6 Polymorphic relation with whereHas

Tags: php, foreign-keys, relational-database, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I am facing an issues in Polymorphic relation where I can not make whereHas to work. Basically I have a "where" condition which i want to apply.
The relation code is working fine to return the related models but it returns errors once applying the whereHas.

Below is the code

Orders Class:

```
class Order extends Model
 {

  // function to return orders 
  public static function getAllOrders()
  { 


    return $orders = Order::with('part.pcategory')->whereHas('part', function ($query) 
         {
                  $query->where('cat_id',4);
         })->get();
  }

  // the relation 
  public function part()
  { 

  return $this->morphTo(null,'department_short_code','part_stock_number','stock_number', 'dep_short_code');
  }

 }
```

SFD Parts Class:

```
class sfd_part extends Model
{

  public function orders()
    {   

    return  $this->morphMany('App\Order','part','department_short_code','part_stock_number');
   }

   public function pcategory()
    {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pcategories','cat_id', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

When i call getAllOrders() it gives the below error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cat_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `orders` where exists (select * from `orders` as `laravel_reserved_0` where `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `laravel_reserved_0`.`part_stock_number` and `cat_id` = 2 and `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `laravel_reserved_0`.`part_stock_number` and `cat_id` = 2))

Database tables structure

[image]

The data am trying to get is a list of orders with each part related. Then i get the category name which is related to this part. Also i want to filter this list by using whereHas where i get for example all orders which came for a specific category which.

Orders table has the orders which linked with part. this part can be in any of the 3 tables, thats  why i used Polymorphic relation relaying on two keys department_short_code and part_stock_number

Comment: can you show me your table structure and what data you want to get ??

Comment: @punk73 i have updated my question. I hope its clear now

Comment: Laravel 5.8.27 adds `whereHasMorph()`: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some issues using whereHas i don't why. this situation can be handled in other way though

> you might not find where method in the editors but it can be used and it works accordingly. use tosql() to further check the query.

```
Order::with('part.pcategory')->where( function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('part_id', function ($query) {
            $query->select('id')
                ->from('sfd_part')
                ->where('cat_id',4);
        });
    })->get();
```

Comment: Not yet the solution but this fix is doing the job partially

Comment: Issue is whereHas method doesn't work on polymorphic relations

Comment: This also returns orders whose part ids have `part_type` different then `sfd_part` class. Including same ids in `sec_parts`and `rmf_parts` table.

Answer (score -2):

You can safely and cleanly use the below code. You are out of Eloquent, but still using laravel functions.

```
Order::with('part.pcategory')
    ->leftJoin('sfd_parts','orders.part_id','=','sfd_parts.id')
    ->where('orders.part_type','=',sfd_parts::class)
    ->where('sfd_parts.cat_id','=',4)
    ->get();
```